# Parse / statically analyzing .NET binaries using python

Tags: static-analysis, python, .net

Which libraries do you use to parse and statically analyze .NET binaries?

Is there a python module, or do I have to use a .NET library such as dnlib? Does it make sense to write a python wrapper for it, e.g. using pythonnet?